Issues with a quotient topological space
Let $X=S^1$ the unit circle and take $p\in X$ and define $A=X\setminus \{p\}$.
Consider the quotient space $Y=X/A$, that means $x\sim y$ iff $x,y\in A$.
Is $Y$ homotopic equivalent to $X$?
My problem is to visualize the quotient. I think that $Y$ is not homotopic equivalent to $X$ because of the identification. But it's fairly complicated.
Any suggestions? Is my intuition right?

I don't understand your definition of the quotient space. You can't take the quotient over a set $A$ instead you have to take the quotient with respect to an equivalence relation. Do you mean that all elements of $A$ are equivalent, so eventually the quotient space $Y$ consists of two points: $p$ and $A$?

Yes, the equivalence relation is that $x\sim y$ iff $x,y\in A$.

Y is just two points. You're identifying everything not equal to p

Yes, and I see that $Y$ it cannot be homotopic equivalent to $X$, but how can I say it more precisely?

No, the quotient is connected (being the continuous image of a connected space)...

I've already proved that a trivial space is always contractible

Are you sure you've described the space $Y$ correctly? It's a fairly pathological space.

The quotient has 2 points but it isn't $T_1$, since the image of $A$ is a point that is not closed. Perhaps you can show the quotient is contractible.

I'm thinking about if it's possible to say that $Y$ is trivial...

@arkeet - I think it's the image of $p$ that isn't closed? Regardless, there are precisely 3 open sets in its topology.

So no, $Y$ doesn't have the trivial topology.

My exercise teacher suggest me to assume that $S^1$ is not contractible, so I think that we have to think a way to prove that $Y$ is conctractible in order to conclude

To summarize, $Y = {[p],A}$ is a space with 2 points, and it has exactly 3 open sets, namely $\varnothing,{A},Y$ (which you should check using the definition of the quotient topology). You want to show it is contractible. Can you come up with a homotopy between the identity map and the constant map at $[p]$? (By the way, $Y$ is often called a Sierpinski space.)

(Oh - strictly speaking, your description of the relation $\sim$ is incorrect as it isn't reflexive - one should say $x \sim y$ iff $x = y$ or $x,y \in A$.)

Thanks to @arkeet's second to last comment, I am voting to close as a "duplicate" of Let $X$ be the Sierpinski space, $X={x,y}$. Prove that $X$ is contractible. and the post linked to it.

I don't really think it's a duplicate - I interpret the question as mainly trying to understand what the quotient space $X/A$ is (and showing it's not homotopy equivalent to $X$ using any means).
